# How to automatically split and sum hourly entries per month and project in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Currently I can sum worked hours per month based on a entry with date and time worked as shown here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DICxDrzv9yctCwBZv5Os0HGnCG76PRdEb_2D9TzXxyE/edit?usp=sharing

My formula to do this goes like this:

```
 =query(ArrayFormula({{unique(text(A2:A,"MMMM-YY"))},
 {sumif(text(A2:A,"MMMM-YY"),
 unique(text(A2:A,"MMMM-YY")),B2:G)}}),"Select * where Col2>0")
```

But now I want an overview per month and project and/or an extra overview with total time per project.

How do I approach this situation?

Feel free to add an extra sheet with your solution as my google drive sheet is public :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Added couple of approaches to your sheet for you to test out:*

```js
=query({index({eomonth(A2:A,),--B2:B}),C2:D},"select Col1,sum(Col2) Where Col4<>'' group by Col1 pivot Col4 order by Col1 label sum(Col2) '' format sum(Col2) 'hh:mm:ss', Col1 'mmmm-yy'")
```

---

```js
=query({index({eomonth(A2:A,),--B2:B}),C2:D},"select Col1,sum(Col2),Col4 Where Col4<>'' group by Col1,Col4 order by Col1 label sum(Col2) '' format sum(Col2) 'hh:mm:ss', Col1 'mmmm-yy'")
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, rockinfreakshow, that's insane! Thank you so much I use both of your approaches. I see you use "group by" like in a SQL query. That makes sense, thank you very much for your help!